# Javascript Regex multi space "\s" doesn't work in chrome

Tags: javascript, regex

I try to use this Regex

```
new RegExp('utm_source=Weekly\SRecommended\SJobs\SEmail', 'ig');
```

When I try to use it in [regex101](https://regex101.com/) or [regexr](http://regexr.com/) it works.

And in my code doesn't work.

I try to use this in console this is the result is

```
/utm_source=WeeklysRecommendedsJobssEmail/gi
```

the code without spaces.

When I try to use space letter it works.

Any help?

Comment: `new RegExp('utm_source=Weekly\\SRecommended\\SJobs\\SEmail', 'ig');`

Comment: I need to know the reasons for this :D

Comment: The reason is that ``\S`` is an *undefined escape sequence* in a JS string literal and backslashes in these escape sequences are just discarded from the string. The problem is known, highly frequent, no need to repeat "double the brackslashes", thus, question is closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `\` is an escape character for regular expressions *and* strings. You have to escape the `\` if you're creating a regex from a string:

```
new RegExp('utm_source=Weekly\\SRecommended\\SJobs\\SEmail', 'ig');
```

Or simply use a regex literal which exists precisely to avoid this problem:

```
/utm_source=Weekly\SRecommended\SJobs\SEmail/ig
```